# shell script to wait for gunzip to complete before going to next line

Tags: linux, shell

I created a shell script to loop through some files in a directory, unzip them, add in a date field, zip them back up, and then move them to the hadoop file system. But, when I run the script, it seems to go right to the next line without waiting for gunzip to complete. How do I tell it to wait for it to complete before moving to the next line?

```
FILENAME="/datatst/toproc/*"

for i in $FILENAME
do
    echo "file name is: " $i
    FILENAMEv2=$(basename "${i}" .gz )
    echo "Stripped file name is: " $FILENAMEv2
    DATEPART=$(echo $i| cut -d"." -f1| cut -d"-" -f2-)
    echo "Datepart is: " $DATEPART
    FileDir="/datatst/unzip/$FILENAMEv2"
    echo "unzip directory file is: " $FileDir
    echo "unzipping file..."
    gunzip $i > -c $FileDir && trash $i
    echo "unzipping done..."
    echo "sed operation begin..."
    sed -i 's/^/'$DATEPART' /g' $FileDir
    echo "sed operation done..."
    echo "zip operation begin..."
    gzip $FileDir -c > /datatst/tomove/$i && trash $FileDir
    su hadoop fs -put /datatst/tomove/$i /user/hdfs/
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try changing ...

```
gunzip $i > -c $FileDir && trash $i
```

... to ...

```
gunzip $i -c > $FileDir && trash $i
```

... I am not sure what the `trash` is.

Updated as per comment from user*

Comment: I thought trash was supposed to delete that file? no?

Comment: @user2061886 maybe it is. But I think you shouldn't be doing the`>`.

Comment: ok, so if I don't do the >, it output everyline to the console...I added in & to end of it but that didn't seem to help...

Comment: @user2061886 : if there are  `&` chars at the end of lines, this means "run in the background", which would give the symptom you are describing. Remove any trailing `&` chars. Good luck.

Comment: ok, so I got it to work like this:  gunzip -c $i > $FileDir && trash $i...I moved the -c after the gunzip and gzip commands...and you were right, trash is not a command...but here is another problem now, SED runs but gzip doesn't wait for SED to complete now...

Comment: Yes that's correct.  you do need the `>` the -c causes gunzip to write to stdout and the `>` redirects stdout to your file `$FileDir`